# r Shiny - How can I use checkboxGroupInput selections to call a vector of the same name?

Tags: r, shiny

Sorry if this question is silly - I am fairly new to Shiny.

I want to use the selections made in a checkboxGroupInput to later call on a pre-defined vector of the same name.

**DATA**

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
age <- c(24,35,64,23,64,74)
height <- c(152,163,174,151,163,173)
colours <- c("blue","red","blue","yellow","blue","green")
lines <- c("wavy","straight","dash","straight","wavy","curly")
highlights <- c("yes","no","no","yes","yes","no)
mydata <- data.frame(id,age,height,colours,lines,highlights)
```

Essentially what I have is a list of variables names that I have grouped into individual categories (vectors). For ease I am just using this small example, but in practice it will be much larger so calling on individual variables is not feasible:

**Variable name groupings**

```
Demographics <- c("id","age","height")
Descriptors <- c("colours","lines","highlights")
```

Now what I want to do is refer back to these pre-defined vectors based on the input selections of the same name (and use to select variables), but I haven't been able to find a way how. E.g. code

I have tried a few things like using `print(input$varchoices)` or `as.character(input$varchoices)` but they don't work.

```
# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
   
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Variable Selector"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       
       # Checkbox for choice of variables
       checkboxGroupInput("varchoices", "Variables", choices=c("Demographics","Descriptors"), selected = "Demographics") 
       
     ),
      mainPanel(
        
        
        # Table output of selected data
        tableOutput("data"),        
   )
   )
)
```

**SERVER**

```
# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {  
  
  # Data selection based on inputs
  newdata <- reactive({
    mydata %>%
    dplyr::select(contains(input$varchoices)) ## Not sure of how proceed here
     })
  
  # Renderable format of selected data
  output$data <- renderTable(newdata(),rownames=TRUE)
  
}
```

Any help is much appreciated thank you!!! I feel like the answer is fleetingly simple I just haven't been able to work it out.

Comment: Try get(input$varchoices)

Comment: That's awesome thank you! With multiple selections though it only returns the first in the list (e.g. "Demographics" in my example) - how can I get multiple selections in the ui to return multiple results?

Comment: Maybe there's a simpler way, but I think this might work for you: `dplyr::select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherit = TRUE))))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing your dplyr::select()` command to @Ben's suggestion should work.

You've already created vector objects with names matching your checkbox inputs that have the selection of columns.  Get will return the object a character string refers to so `get("Demographics")` will return

```
> get("Demographics")
[1] "id"     "age"    "height"

### and 
> get("Descriptors")
[1] "colours"    "lines"      "highlights"
```

But `get()` only returns a single item, so you need `mget()`, which accepts zero or more items, so doesn't fail if more than one box is checked. To make mget work with dplyr::select you need to convert it from a named list into an unnamed character vector, hence `unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE)))`. This will return a character vector of the column names identified by your checkbox and character vectors.

```
library(dplyr)

mydata %>%
      select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE))))

# Testing with all possible values:
input$varchoices <- character()
mydata %>%
      select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE))))
# data frame with 0 columns and 6 rows

> input$varchoices <- "Descriptors"
> mydata %>%
+       select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE))))
  colours    lines highlights
1    blue     wavy        yes
2     red straight         no
3    blue     dash         no
4  yellow straight        yes
5    blue     wavy        yes
6   green    curly         no

> input$varchoices <- "Demographics"
> mydata %>%
+       select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE))))
  id age height
1  1  24    152
2  2  35    163
3  3  64    174
4  4  23    151
5  5  64    163
6  6  74    173

> input$varchoices <- c("Demographics", "Descriptors")
> mydata %>%
+       select(unname(unlist(mget(input$varchoices, inherits = TRUE))))
  id age height colours    lines highlights
1  1  24    152    blue     wavy        yes
2  2  35    163     red straight         no
3  3  64    174    blue     dash         no
4  4  23    151  yellow straight        yes
5  5  64    163    blue     wavy        yes
6  6  74    173   green    curly         no
```

Comment: great, thank you!! I was trying to get `mget` to work but couldn't - `unname` and `unlist` is the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MWE:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Variable Selector"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        "varchoices", 
        "Variables", 
        choices=c("Demographics","Descriptors"), selected = "Demographics")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # Table output of selected data
      tableOutput("data")
    )
  )
)

mydata <- tibble(id=rnorm(10), age=rnorm(10), height=rnorm(10), colours=rnorm(10), lines=rnorm(10), highlights=rnorm(10))
varGroups <- list(
              "Demographics"=c("id","age","height"),
              "Descriptors"=c("colours","lines","highlights")
             )

server <- function(input, output) {
  newdata <- reactive({
    req(input$varchoices)
    
    names <- unlist(lapply(input$varchoices, function(x) varGroups[[x]]))
    mydata %>%
       dplyr::select(names)
  })

  output$data <- renderTable(newdata(),rownames=TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How does it work?

First, I've placed your variable groups in a list (and also generated some random data to work with):

```
mydata <- tibble(id=rnorm(10), age=rnorm(10), height=rnorm(10), colours=rnorm(10), lines=rnorm(10), highlights=rnorm(10))
varGroups <- list(
              "Demographics"=c("id","age","height"),
              "Descriptors"=c("colours","lines","highlights")
             )
```

Then, I convert the groups selected in `input$varchoices` to a vector of variable names...

```
    names <- unlist(lapply(input$varchoices, function(x) varGroups[[x]]))
```

...and use the vector in `select`.

```
    mydata %>%
       dplyr::select(names)
```

Finally, to allow for the situation when no groups are selected, add

```
req(input$varchoices)
```

at the start of the `newdata` reactive.

The approach is easily generalisable: just update the `varGroups` list every time you change your variable groupings.